# git не запрашивает пароль при push

Tags: git, github

Ввожу команду

```
git push -u origin master
```

выводит:

> remote: Permission to dpApps/A.git denied to densektor1. fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/dpApps/A.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

densektor1  - это мой старый аккаунт.

Естественно, меня не пускает с этим логином на новый (dpApps). Как его перенастроить?

В файле `.git/config`:

```
[user]
    name = dpApps
    email = teamDevelopers@yandex.ru
[gc]
    autoDetach = false
[gui]
    recentrepo = C:/Users/Denis/Desktop/Adviser
```

Comment: что в файле gitconfig? или что выдаёт `git config` в консоли?

Comment: [user]
 name = dpApps
 email = teamDevelopers@yandex.ru
[gc]
 autoDetach = false
[gui]
 recentrepo = C:/Users/Denis/Desktop/Adviser

Comment: Вроде верный и логин, и эмейл

Comment: посмотрите вопрос и принятый ответ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335197/gits-famous-error-permission-to-git-denied-to-user

Comment: Если origin подключен по http (а похоже так оно и есть) - отвяжите локальный репо от удаленного и снова создайте, только уже с новым пользователем. А еще лучше - подключите по ssh (создайте id_rsa и добавьте его в профиль гитхаба)